# Disabling multiple recaptchas after one is clicked in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies, recaptcha

I have two recaptchas enabled on a client's wordpress site for a search form. Each recaptcha is on a separate page. Both are attached to search forms that hit the same api.

I'm wondering how to disable/hide both recaptchas if one is checked.

I've tried using a session, which worked in staging but not in production because of caching.

I've also tried using cookies, but I don't know how to make one page read another page's cookie.

I'm using the standard google recaptcha script

```
<script>
                grecReady = function(){
                    grecaptcha.render('grec', {
                        'sitekey' : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                        'callback' : function(g){
                            document.cookie = "grecResponse="+g;
                            jQuery('#grec').addClass('clicked');
                        }
                    });
                }
</script>
```

*edit for clarity*: We're using recaptcha version 2.

Also, recaptcha 1 creates a cookie associated with the path '/somepage'.

Recaptcha 2 creates a cookie associated with the path '/somepage/subpage'.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which version of `recaptcha` are you using ?

Comment: We're using recaptcha v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update 2019-10-16:

Our problem was the hefty caching that WPengine does with our client's site. We used an ajax call to create the global cookie with the help of these articles:

https://wp-time.com/wordpress-ajax-tutorial-and-example/
https://wpshout.com/using-cookies-in-wordpress-part-ii-cache-busting-with-ajax/

We also had to exclude the cookie and the pages using recaptchas from caching with the help of WPengine customer service.

This is a 90% solution. If we click the back button after passing the recaptcha, the recaptcha form is shown because the page is still being cached. WPengine was unable to do anything else to help.

It's a 90% solution, but the client is happy. Hope this helps someone else.